# Augmented reality webcame error

Tags: augmented-reality, unity-game-engine

I'm working an augmented reality application using unity 5.
I'm having an error:

```
Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/QCARWrapper.dll', expected 64 bit architecture 
(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64), but was IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386. You must 
recompile your plugin for 64 bit architecture.
```

any help?

Comment: You are trying to use a 32 .dll in a 64 bit programm, that does not work. Either get a 64bit version of that plugin, or set Unity to 32bit (if that is possible)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and had to install Unity 32bits to get Vuforia working the properly on my project. 
You can download the latest 32 bit Unity Editor from [here](http://netstorage.unity3d.com/unity/44735ea161b3/Windows32EditorInstaller/UnitySetup32-5.2.1f1.exe). 
If you are looking for a specific version, [here is the full list](http://unity3d.com/es/get-unity/download/archive).